# Accessing Singletons in a Closure = Memory Leak?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, closures, retain-cycle

Does accessing a singleton within a closure cause a retain cycle?

Specifically something like this example:

```
class TheSingleton
{
    static let shared = TheSingleton() //THE SINGLETON

    enum Temperature              //An associated enum
    {
        case cold, hot
    }

    var currentTemp: Temperature? //A non-class-type variable
    var aPicture: UIImage?        //A class-type variable

    func giveMeFive() -> Int      //A function
    {
         return 5
    }

    //Pay attention to this
    func doSomething(onDone: @escaping (Int) -> ())
    {
         OtherSVC.upload("Mr. Server, do async stuff plz") { (inImage) in
             TheSingleton.shared.currentTemp = .cold
             TheSingleton.shared.aPicture = inImage
             onDone(TheSingleton.shared.giveMeFive())
         }
    }
}
//Fire the thing
TheSingleton.shared.doSomething { _ in}
```

If so, I don't really know how to write a capture list for this...

```
[weak TheSingleton.shared] (inImage) in
```

You can't do that ^

I included three cases because maybe the type of data matters?
I think I'm missing some fundamentals on capture lists and closure retain cycles.

All I know is whenever you access something outside of a closure's curly braces, you have to unown/weak it if it's a class-type object.
That's because closures create strong references by default.

I thought I could be cheeky and get around retain cycles by calling the entire singleton in closures, but I'm probably being dumb by turning a blind eye.

Would a solution be to do something like:

```
var updateDis = TheSingleton.shared.aPicture
OtherSVC.upload("ugh this is lame, and more work") { [unowned updateDis] inPic in 
    updateDis = inPic
}
```

?

Comment: Offtopic: Please fix those {}'s. Put a { right after a method/class, not beneath them. In your last code example it is good.

Comment: @J.Doe, isn't this a matter of opinion? Sure, Apple docs don't newline their braces, but I think it's easier to read if the braces have their own line. It also gives me a way to differentiate between a method/class and Swift's sugary trailing closure syntax.

Comment: Ofcourse, you can put everything in 1 line if you want, but all style guides you will find for Swift will say that it needs to be on the same line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are writing a singleton, `TheSingleton.shared` is pretty much always going to be the same thing as `self`, so capture `unowned self` or `weak self` instead. I would prefer `weak` here because `self` will pretty much always be retained by the class and will only be deallocated when the application terminates.

```
OtherSVC.upload("Mr. Server, do async stuff plz") { [unowned self] (inImage) in
    self..currentTemp = .cold
    self.aPicture = inImage
    onDone(self.giveMeFive())
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I would argue that with the (correct) arguments you bring up it actually does not matter that a retain cycle is created: the singleton will never be deallocated anyway, so you could just use the strong ref inside the closure. I wouldn't do that either, but at least I'd rather go with `unowned` (as in your example) because it's nicer to work with than `weak` is. Am I missing something obvious here? Do you suggest `weak` for _stylistic_ reasons or is there a hidden danger I don't see?

Comment: @dr_barto no, I suggested weak just for completeness. Because if you used weak there won’t be any problems either, it’s just that you have to deal with optionals. Thus I prefer unowned.

Comment: Ok, got it -- that was my thinking as well :)

Comment: Ok, but what about accessing other singletons?

Comment: @XavierL. As dr_barto said, singletons are never deallocated when the app is running anyway. So just don’t write a capture list.

Comment: @Sweeper So basically, what I was doing is all right then. Calling the entire qualifier for the singleton is equivalent to using self without a capture list (it just requires more unnecessary typing). The closure gets deallocated fine, and there are no leaks anywhere.

Comment: @XavierL. Yeah that’s right. Note that whether the closure gets deallocated properly depends on where the closure escapes to. If it escapes to, say, a property of an object, it will stay until that object is deallocated or that property is set to nil.